# Android WebView extract JSON

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

Due to some circumstances, JSON is being retrieved using a Webview.
What's the best way to extract the JSON? As far as I know, has to be via Javascript. What exactly to call in the Javacript: `document.GetElementsByTagName('body')`? Is there any other better way?
Because looks like the JSON is automatically encapsulated in some HTML by Webview.

For now, it won't be possible to retrieve JSON via HttpClient, which would be the best option.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your JSON? is it stored in any element in DOM or in javascript variable?

Comment: @bhargavg no, it's returned from the HTTP request. But the client, instead of using HttpClient, is using a Webview to do the request.

Comment: I didn't understand, is your javascript making the HTTP request?

Comment: @bhargavg No. I just open the URL of the JSON in the Webview.

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerText` solved the issue.